How can I fix an HTML object in place when scrolling right, but allow it to disappear from view when scrolling down?
I have a webpage with a header bar across the top. When the content of my page is too wide (typically caused by an embedded object) I would like the header bar across the top to still display across the entire width of the screen. However, when I scroll down on my page, I want this header bar to disappear from view.
Essentially, I want the header to behave like its position is "absolute" when scrolling down, but "fixed" when scrolling right. What is the best way to achieve this?
I tried using position: fixed, position: absolute, and position: sticky without any luck. I also spent some time looking for resources online that address this, but couldn't find anyone talking about this specifically.
Editing to include some of the code I have been using as a simple example. Since most people are suggesting position: sticky is the way to go, I gave that a try, but I assume I am not applying this properly since it is still not working as intended.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        .top-border {
            width: 100%;
            position: sticky;
            left: 0;
        }
        .content {
            margin-top: 60px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .box {
            width: 5000px;
            height: 2000px;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, grey, black);
        }
        .topborderthick {
            background-color: #155c35;
            height: 30px;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .topborderlight {
            background: #68a36b;
            height: 8px;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        .headerbutton {
            color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block; 
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top-border" class="top-border">
        <div class="topborderthick">
            <a class="headerbutton" href="#">HOME</a>
            <a class="headerbutton" href="#">ACCOUNT</a>
            <a class="headerbutton" href="#">LOGOUT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="topborderlight"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>This is an Example</h1>
        <p>The green bar at the top of the page should disappear from view when scrolling down, but should remain fixed in place when scrolling to the right.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>


Please show what you have tried, particularly sticky would seem to be what you are looking for so we need to see what your structure is to find why it isn't working.

...and how is the element's width defined?

The problem is basically that widths were not defined.
You want the top bar to fill the viewport so this snippet gives it a width of 100vw but you want the body to be the full width of the content.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      width: fit-content;
    }
    
    .top-border {
      width: 100vw;
      /* was % */
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .content {
      margin-top: 60px;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .box {
      width: 5000px;
      height: 2000px;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, grey, black);
    }
    
    .topborderthick {
      background-color: #155c35;
      height: 30px;
      width: 100%;
      /* was % */
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .topborderlight {
      background: #68a36b;
      height: 8px;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .headerbutton {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="top-border" class="top-border">
    <div class="topborderthick">
      <a class="headerbutton" href="#">HOME</a>
      <a class="headerbutton" href="#">ACCOUNT</a>
      <a class="headerbutton" href="#">LOGOUT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="topborderlight"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>This is an Example</h1>
    <p>The green bar at the top of the page should disappear from view when scrolling down, but should remain fixed in place when scrolling to the right.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>

</html>




Thank you! This looks to have handled it-- I really appreciate you taking the time to help with this!

In continuing to test this solution, I am realizing this has one small consequence. When my content is too tall to fit the page and a vertical scroll bar is added, then a horizontal scroll bar is also added for a few pixel's worth of space since vw doesn't account for the width of the scroll bar like % does. Is there any good workaround for this, or is that just the tradeoff I will have to make?
